# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception when starting process - file not found, but file exists

Tags: c#, exception, file-access, file-not-found, win32exception

I am trying to create a manager for my autostarts. It should read an XML file and then start my programs with a custom delay. For example:

```
<startup id="0">
    <name>Realtek Audio Manager</name>
    <process arguments="-s">C:\Program Files\Realtek\Audio\HDA\RtkNGUI64.exe</process>
    <delay>5</delay>
</startup>
```

This runs the specified process (`C:\Program Files\...\RtkNGUI64.exe -s`) after 5 seconds.

Now, three of the programs won't start, giving me a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`: "Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden." ("The system was not able to find the specified file.")

But the XML is parsed correctly, and the file I want to start is at the location I specified in the XML file.

The problem concerns only these three files:
Intel HotkeysCmd - C:\Windows\System32\hkcmd.exe
Intel GFX Tray - C:\Windows\System32\igfxtray.exe
Intel Persistance - C:\Windows\System32\igfxpers.exe

I think that the problem comes from the location of the files: they all are located in C:\Windows\System32, and all the other, working programs are located outside (C:\Program Files, C:\Program Files (x86), D:\Program Files, `%AppData%`)

Do I have to give my program some kind of access rights to start programs in C:\Windows\System32? How would I do that?

If not, what could be the reason I get errors with these programs?

EDIT - my code:

```
delegate(object o)
{
    var s = (Startup) o;
    var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process
                {
                    StartInfo =
                        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(s.Process, s.Arguments)
                };
    try
    {
        s.Process = @"C:\Windows\System32\igfxtray.exe"; // For debugging purposes
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s.Process);
        icon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "StartupManager",
                            "\"" + s.Name + "\" has been started.",
                            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info);
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
    {
        icon.ShowBalloonTip(2000, "StartupManager",
                            "\"" + s.Name + "\" could not be found.",
                            System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just doing:             System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\igfxtray.exe");

I tried that (I have igfxtray on my machine) and I got no error at all.

Comment: The line you used works for me too, but when I use a variable (`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(s.Process)`) (where s is a `struct Startup` containing `string Process`), it just won't start, although `s.Process == "C:\\Windows\\System32\\igfxtray.exe"`.

Comment: It can be disabled. Was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487653/how-can-disable-redirection-on-win64/17487922#17487922?newreg=7472b07aa3024bcf9f77584134a1cc72

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Clearly you are using a 64-bit version of Windows.  The c:\windows\system32 and c:\program files directories are subject to a feature called "file system redirection".  It is an appcompat feature, it helps to ensure that 32-bit processes don't try to use 64-bit executables.  They'll get *redirected* to c:\windows\syswow64 and c:\program files (x86).

So when you try to start a file in c:\program files\realtek\etcetera, your 32-bit program will be redirected to c:\program files (x86)\realtek\etcetera.  A directory that doesn't exist, kaboom.  Same ingredient for igfxtray.exe

You'll need to change your program's platform target so it can run as a native 64-bit process and avoid the redirection problem you now have.  Project + Properties, Build tab, change the "Platform target" setting to AnyCPU.