# Why i'm getting a win32exception once i'm starting the Process?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, win32exception

This is the code in the ffmpeg.cs class where the process is start .
My brother tried to run the ffmpeg.exe alone and it's working no problems but once he click the button and the process is start he is getting an exception :

My brother have windows xp 32bit while i'm using windows 8 64bit but the ffmpeg.exe is 32bit version and it's working on my machine.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;
        string ffmpegFileName;
        string workingDirectory;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {
            workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath) + @"\workingDirectory";
            ffmpegFileName = @"\ffmpeg.exe";
            if (!Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(workingDirectory);
            }
            ffmpegFileName = workingDirectory + ffmpegFileName;
        }

        public void Start(string pathFileName, int BitmapRate)
        {
            string outPath = pathFileName;
            p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
            b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psi.FileName = ffmpegFileName;
            psi.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            psi.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + outPath;
            //psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process = Process.Start(psi);
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            p.WaitForConnection();
        }
```

This is the exception message he get on his computer :

```
Application: ScreenVideoRecorder.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
Stack:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo)
   at ScreenVideoRecorder.Ffmpeg.Start(System.String, Int32)
   at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.gkh_KeyDown(System.Object, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs)
   at Utilities.globalKeyboardHook.hookProc(Int32, Int32, keyboardHookStruct ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.PeekMessage(MSG ByRef, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)
   at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main()
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Try targeting the .NET executable to 32bit and see what happens. Could be that it tries to run ffmpeg in 64bit mode.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974653/system-componentmodel-win32exception-when-starting-process-file-not-found-but) for a similar error

Comment: When you ran the program on your brother's machine did you pass in the same command line arguments as the code does?  Also, does your brother's monitor support 1920x1080 resolution?

Comment: Same arguments command line i sent him the same compiled program im using targeting x86

Comment: @joneK did you manage to fix it? did you find out the problem? I am facing same problem but with a windows 7