# not able to launch narrator .exe 64 bit from a 32 bit application

Tags: c#, narrator

i am trying to launch narrator.exe from my c# code in visual studio but it continuously throws an exception . the code which i am using is 
:: " Process NarratorProcess = process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\narrator.exe");"
but it continuously throws an exception saying ::

threw exception: 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

however the file is present in the specified location . I googled and found it may be due to windows file system redirection as in this article [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception when starting process - file not found, but file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974653/system-componentmodel-win32exception-when-starting-process-file-not-found-but)     and also followed the steps mentioned there but still it doesnot work. Can someone help me out .

Comment: Probably `C:\Windows\Sysnative\narrator.exe` works?

Comment: It will be down to the redirector. Maybe you skimmed over things in the linked question too quickly?

Comment: i didn't get you @Damien_The_Unbeliever how to stop that redirection ? because i tried the settings mentioned  in the linked question to my project it didn't work ?

Comment: solved it by disabling redirection as in the link below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487653/how-can-disable-redirection-on-win64